# Need help for Coturn configuration for my public ip address

Tags: webrtc, stun, turn, coturn

I have tried with coturn configuration in my local system using my local IP address. It worked. But now, I'm trying to configure my public IP to avoid the ICE Framework. Is it possible? and I'm doing this using Cygwin, can I able to configure this in my system with my public IP address?

Answer (score 1):

If using command line for configuration use, `-L private_IP -X public_IP`

Or, in config file, set 
`external-ip=public_ip/private_ip` and use private IP as listening IP.

For aws system I am using this command

```
sudo turnserver -v -o -a -user username:key -f -L private_ip -X public_ip -E private_ip -min-port=minport_number -max-port=max_port_number -r public_ip --no-tls --no-dtls
```

Comment: Can I know what you're saying as a private IP? Whether its an inet address of that public server? @sumana

Comment: When you are behind a router or any other NAT device, the IP of your computer is private IP and the IP of the device directly connected to internet(example: router) is public IP.
For google search "my ip", it shows public IP. it will different from your system IP when you are connected with a router.

Comment: Oooh Okay fine Now what I did is,I directly made the connection for my centos using putty and I have followed this link to make connection https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/docs/TURN-server-installation-guide.html#centos I have done all the steps as per the document
But the thing I'm getting is 

Cannot bind the local socket to addr:PERMISSION DENIED

But I have done all the steps @sumana

Comment: looking like, it's a permission error. Please use 'sudo' when you are running turn server

Comment: Ya, I successfully did it. But how can I test it whether its working or not? As of now, I don't need any errors !! @sumana

Comment: [Test Turn server](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/trickle-ice/)

You may use this one. After adding your server, hit gather candidate. If you see 3 type of component(host, srflx and relay) in component type field, then your server is working fine.

Comment: Time Component Type Foundation Protocol Address Port Priority
0.002 1 host 2445384676 udp 192.168.1.26 55696 126 | 32542 | 255
0.041 1 srflx 1741808176 udp 183.82.38.198 27826 100 | 32542 | 255
0.104 1 host 3745670932 tcp 192.168.1.26 9 90 | 32542 | 255
0.827 Done
0.829

Comment: This means STUN is working fine. To check relay try to test from a different network than the network where your turn server is.

This is a very [helpful link](https://addpipe.com/blog/troubleshooting-webrtc-connection-issues/)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185049/discussion-between-sumana-and-ashika).